# Why does the reflector not show that IDictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ienumerable, idictionary

I noticed that key-value pairs can only be added to Dictionaries if the variable is declared as an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Which caused me to dig further down the rabbit hole, leading me to discover that there seems to be an odd discrepancy:

1. Microsoft Docs explicitly confirm that `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`

   [Microsoft Docs Screenshot - IDictionary Implements implements `IEnumerable<T>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiXoM.png)
2. Using the Visual Studio's Reflector Tool on mscorlib, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` seems to not implement `IEnumerable<T>`

   [Reflector Tool Screenshot - mscorlib, IDictionary seems to not implement `IEnumerable<T>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuyqV.png)

Any explanation will be helpful to sate this curious mind!

Comment: Your screenshot shows, that it does implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, where `T` is deducted as `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: What is `T` in this context? We have only  `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @Carsten I thought the same, but it doesn't make much sense to me, because it's already specified with `IEnumrable<KeyValue<`

Comment: Well, the docs are wrong. It can't possibly implement `IEnumerable<T>` because `T` is not a generic parameter of `IDictionary`! Note, however, that `IEnumerable` (in all flavors) is not relevant to your question anyway, as `IEnumerable` doesn't contain any methods for adding. `ICollection` does, but that method will typically be implemented explicitly, so as to not cause confusion with the dictionary's own `Add` method (taking a key and value).

Comment: [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/F/workspace/_work/1/s/bin/repo/runtime/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/IDictionary.cs/IDictionary.cs,12) definition

Comment: Uh, yeah. The MSDN docs are simply generated by a tool, and that tool isn't perfect. The source code is always correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **does** show that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

[image]

For a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, the collection element's type is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. In essence, a dictionary is an enumerable list of key/value pairs (of the chosen key/value types), so it implements the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface.

The MSDN docs show *both* the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and the more concrete `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, but they are referring to the same implementation. The `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` is effectively `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

This isn't a case of the real code missing a documented feature. It's a case of MSDN documenting the same interface implementation twice, by referring to both the generic `IEnumerable<T>` *and* the more concrete type where it shows what `T` is being defined as (i.e. `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`).

---

If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to have `Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<T>` since `T` was never defined to begin with. Any generic type that appears after the `:` must either be hardcoded or defined as a generic type before the `:`, and `T` is neither hardcoded nor defined, so it's not valid syntax.

You can easily confirm this behavior:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<string> { } // allowed, T is hardcoded as string

public class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }   // allowed, T is defined in Foo<T>

public class Foo : IEnumerable<T> { }      // error, T is neither hardcoded nor defined
```

Knowing this, let's look back at the dictionary:

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<T>  // error, T is neither hardcoded nor defined
```

But this *is* valid:

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` consists of 3 distinct types, and all of them conform to the rules:

- `KeyValuePair` is hardcoded (it's a known type)
- `TKey` is a defined generic type from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
- `TValue` is a defined generic type from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

And therefore this class definition is syntactically valid.